# Unable to open Google's secure websites over HTTPS

Tags: settings, connection-issues, https

I can easily open https secured sites on my Win7 laptop (using Google Chrome).
But this is not possible with Chrome version 18.0.1025308 on my ONDA VI30W tablet (running ICS 4.0.3).

What do I need to do? Any suggestion?

1. I bought this tablet online from a distributor of ONDA tablet in China. I myself lives around Montreal, Québec.
2. I can open HTTP and HTTPS on any other sites except GOOGLE sites.
3. I have no access to PLAY STORE as I have to sign in and then  comes up and ask me my google account which I never been able to add to my tablet. I often get "can't establish a reliable connection to the server". I suspect a DNS problem.

Comment: 1. Is this from within China (great firewall...)? 2. Do insecure sites open just fine? 3. Have a look at the logs using the [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) logviewer app. Maybe this gives you further insight.

Comment: Hi, I bought this tablet online from a distributor of ONDA tablet in China. I myself lives around Montreal, Québec.

Comment: Hi, I bought this tablet online from a distributor of ONDA tablet in China. I myself lives around Montreal, Québec. (2) I can open HTTP and HTTPS on any other sites except GOOGLE sites. (3) I have no access to PLAY STORE as I have to sign in and then HTTPS://accounts.google comes up and ask me my google account which I never been able to add to my tablet. I often get "can't establish a reliable connection to the server". I suspect a DNS problem. Thanks Marc

Comment: That sounds *really* fishy. Google & China are not so much a love story, is someone playing Man-in-the-middle here? Or trying to eavesdrop on you? Do you have any means to sniff traffic and/or further analyze this weird bug/problem report? I'd really like to get my hands on this, FYI. Just to sort out if it's only a bug or a *real* malicious intent (like a backdoor or default MitM. Would you mind doing some  research for me (I'll instruct you)?

Comment: That sounds really fishy....... are you addressing these comments and questions to me Marc Gagnon??

Comment: Yes, I meant the facts you stated. (fishy==suspicious, foul, dubious). It seems interesting hence my call for deeper inspection, just to see *whats going on here*.